# Is it possible to have a "dynamic array" inside MATCH function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large amount of data that was converted to excel recently.
There are just two columns and more than 100000 lines. There is an [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITnjE.jpg) as an example attached here.

The systems are always in the second columns as well as the data, but the loads and the rest of the information are in the first column, as you can see in the example, the "Max load" always repeat, but in the system 001 there is a difference of two lines between it and the system name, but in the second system the difference is three lines. I want to make a table for Max load with all the systems, those are the things I tried:

I used MATCH to find the line where the System name appears, knowing that the difference would be either 2 or 3 lines,  I made a table with 2 and 3 in the header and I added it to the line I found and MATCH, it kind of work, but I wanted something better than this improvisation.
I also tried using (where X2= the line where the system name appears)

> =MATCH(AA1;OFFSET(A1:X2:0:100:1);0)

Because I thought that OFFSET would return a range to MATCH, but it didn't work.

I want to know if there is a way to find the text "Max load" after the line I found using the Systems' names in MATCH. Basically, I want to know if there is a way of using kind of a "dynamic array" inside MATCH, so I would use it to find "Max load" right after the system that I am looking for.

I don't if this works, but if there is any other way of doing it, I am glad to know about it.

Thanks very much,

Matheus

Comment: I think only filtering MAX Loads with value will give you desired result if Systems are sorted what your image shows.

Comment: With the amount of data you mentioned it won't be effective /easy to process with formulas. It'd use power query instead (https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/combine-data-from-multiple-data-sources-power-query-70cfe661-5a2a-4d9d-a4fe-586cc7878c7d?ui=en-us&rs=en-gb&ad=gb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple match with index. Use below formula. It will not care how many rows are different from system to data.

```
=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(H4,D:D,0)+MATCH("Max Load",INDIRECT("C" & MATCH(H4,D:D,0) & ":C200000"),0)-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing, it worked perfectly well, thanks Harun24HR.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overthinking this way too much. If you just have either two or three rows, if offsetting the answer by 1 gives you 0 then use a simple if statement to offset it by 3.

```
=IF(INDEX(E:E,MATCH(H3,E:E,0)+2)>0,INDEX(E:E,MATCH(H3,E:E,0)+2),INDEX(E:E,MATCH(H3,E:E,0)+3))
```

[image]

Comment: In my example, the difference is either 2 or 3 lines, but in the real situation it is quite random, but still, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option

In `I4`, formula copied right to `J4` and all copied down :

```
=INDEX($D:$D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$6:$C$1000)/($C$6:$C$1000=I$3),ROW($A1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help bosco_yip! It worked well, but since it does not use the system itself as a reference, it is a little problematic, in my example, the systems are in order, but in the sheet itself, the systems do not follow a specific order. I could use your way after some adaptation, still, thanks.

Comment: Could you  just explain how the array inside AGGREGATE work: I didn't understand with the division results in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be

```
=INDEX(INDEX($D:$D,MATCH($F4,$D:$D,0)):$D$200000,MATCH(G$3,INDEX($C:$C,MATCH($F4,$D:$D,0)):$C$200000,0))
```

[image]

Comment: I tried it here, but it is not working for some reason, I got other solutions. Thanks.